# Return data of callback function Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, ejs

I'm using the 500px API module with Node.js and I'm trying to get photos of a specific user. I'm facing issue with function, callback and scope... I've this code :

```
    api500px.photos.getByUsername ('username', {'sort': 'created_at', 'image_size': '3'}, function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        var dataPx = results.photos;
    });
```

I want to get out my variable `dataPx` and use it in my ejs template :

```
    app.get('/materialize', function(req, res) {
        res.render('materialize.ejs', {dataPx: dataPx});
    });
```

If someone could explain me how to do that and how this kind of things work in JavaScript it would be cool !!!

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how is your app structure, but First Simple solution is below:

```
app.get('/materialize', function(req, res) {            
    api500px.photos.getByUsername ('username', {'sort': 'created_at', 'image_size': '3'}, function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        var dataPx = results.photos;
        res.render('materialize.ejs', {dataPx: dataPx});
    });
  });
```

**OR** adopt better and cleaner approach, use [q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q),

Wrap `api500px.photos.getByUsername` in a promise as:

```
function getUserPhotosAsync() {
  var deferred = q.defer();
      api500px.photos.getByUsername ('username', {'sort': 'created_at', 'image_size': '3'}, function(error, results) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            deferred.resolve(results.photos);
        }); 
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And use it as:

```
   app.get('/materialize', function(req, res) {
      getUserPhotosAsync().then(function(dataPx) { //looks cool isn't it?
        res.render('materialize.ejs', {dataPx: dataPx});
      });
    });
```

Happy Helping!